# LaTeX errors from Doxygen Output - Undefined tab position

Tags: latex, doxygen, pdflatex, tex

I am getting LaTeX Error: Undefined tab position, and pdfLatex quits after receving too many (100 errors). My LaTeX generated by Doxygen is such (one instance of many)

```
\begin{tabbing}
xx\=xx\=xx\=xx\=xx\=xx\=xx\=xx\=xx\=\kill
struct \{\\
\>vuint32\_t \mbox{\hyperlink{union_a_d_c___a_w_o_r_r0__tag_ae48e32e4ce461a344d495ac389b30869}{\+\_\+unused\+\_\+0}}:24\\
\>vuint32\_t \mbox{\hyperlink{union_a_d_c___a_w_o_r_r0__tag_a633552ebdbbbf8732201889e3178c4d1}{AWOR\+\_\+\+CH7}}:1\\
\>vuint32\_t \mbox{\hyperlink{union_a_d_c___a_w_o_r_r0__tag_ae7defeac410a3d696a11b21cee4ccefc}{AWOR\+\_\+\+CH6}}:1\\
\>vuint32\_t \mbox{\hyperlink{union_a_d_c___a_w_o_r_r0__tag_a9395233b09b63e9c10c334d895d14b80}{AWOR\+\_\+\+CH5}}:1\\
\>vuint32\_t \mbox{\hyperlink{union_a_d_c___a_w_o_r_r0__tag_a19bdee16abc81ce4467ffad3323d32ae}{AWOR\+\_\+\+CH4}}:1\\
\>vuint32\_t \mbox{\hyperlink{union_a_d_c___a_w_o_r_r0__tag_ad18e33682f160ec4b6524cb09d66b066}{AWOR\+\_\+\+CH3}}:1\\
\>vuint32\_t \mbox{\hyperlink{union_a_d_c___a_w_o_r_r0__tag_a0b9b29aa48592a60bed0b63f30f3fa73}{AWOR\+\_\+\+CH2}}:1\\
\>vuint32\_t \mbox{\hyperlink{union_a_d_c___a_w_o_r_r0__tag_a12dd10b2002e77b620f80004c9b7cc4d}{AWOR\+\_\+\+CH1}}:1\\
\>vuint32\_t \mbox{\hyperlink{union_a_d_c___a_w_o_r_r0__tag_a58c5f67b10b98181087d17d87e73b690}{AWOR\+\_\+\+CH0}}:1\\
\} {\bfseries B}\\

\end{tabbing}\end{DoxyCompactItemize}
```

I found this [StackExchange Topic](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56793/tabbing-environment-how-to-line-break) that discusses `\+` and `\-` but I am seeing `\+` and `\_`. This [article](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-underscore#:~:text=The%20underscore%20character%20_%20is%20ordinarily,%5C_%20is%20an%20established%20alias.) mentions that the latter is an alias. I am thinking Doxygen has its output format wrong, causing a systemic error. Or am I missing something in my Doxygen or pdfLaTeX configuration?

Doxygen 1.9.6

MiKTeX Console 4.9

Comment: As far as I can tell it has to do with an anonymous type scope and I don't think it is a wrong usage of doxygen (version?) or pdflatex, though to be able to get to the problem the best would be to show some source code that leads to the problem or to file an issue in the doxygen issue tracker with a, small, example.

Comment: Is this about MPC5602D_1M18Y_0203.h as wih this I can reproduce the problem with thde doxygen 1.9.6 version but when using the ciurrent master version (1.9.7 (e5d89df5c17ed801cb2264b1048d4c971ae2fe7d)) it all runs (and I get a large document)